# fresh installation of gvim on ubuntu. where should I put my plugins?

Tags: vim, snipmate

I just installed gvim on fresh installation of ubuntu lucid.  I've messed this up before that's why I want to start on the correct step here.

Where should I keep all my `plugins` and my `.vimrc?`?

my current runtimepath on gvim is:

> runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim72,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after

one thing that i've never been able to get working on gvim is snipMate.  Anyone has pointers on having that work with gvim?

Answer (score 4):

I use [pathogen](http://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) with `~/.vimrc` and plugins in `~/.vim/bundle`, [more details here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332). You can see an [example here](http://github.com/kfl62/dotfiles).

Answer (score 1):

Plugin folder is always under ~home/.vim or ~home/vimfiles your vim configuration file or .vimrc always in your ~home/ as for example: ~home/.vimrc

Snipmate fully works for me under Ubuntu. unzip it correclty and it should work right. BTW a great great plugin.